# Drawable folders for themes

Tags: android, themes, drawable

Since it is possible to set up drawable folders for different purpose like language, dpi, orientation, is it possible to name forders for themes too?

Something like: drawable-mytheme-hdpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. The `aapt` tool that processes resources limits the use of drawable folders to specific qualifiers. Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources for a table with the allowable options: unfortunately {themename} is not one of them.